# Send hotkeys to Silk webdriver

Tags: test-automation-framework, silktest

I use Silk Webdriver to make Selenium tests.

In my application there are a lot of hotkeys (functions keys and ctrl+key combinations) to make the application easier to use.

How can I send those hotkeys to my Silk Webdriver (to test if they work and to shorten the scripts) while recording the scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn’t supported in Silk WebDriver at the moment. Please raise a feature request at the Silk WebDriver UserVoice Portal for further tracking: http://borland.uservoice.com/forums/591958-silk-webdriver

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion, I made a request and got a reply that it will be included in a future release see [my request](https://borland.uservoice.com/forums/591958-silk-webdriver/suggestions/33463531-hotkeys?tracking_code=ff70b98dcdaf8cf78bcd056e99edebea)